# How to find the exact location of leaks in Memory for React Native iOS app

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, memory-leaks

I have an react native app with a dashboard screen containing a Tab-bar at the bottom with 4 screen. I have seen 10-15 memory leaks in the profiler instruments via XCODE. Instruments just show the memory address nothing else. I tried to copy the address and filter out in the debugger navigator but it only shows the Malloc Blocks. I want to know which component is causing the leaks or which code file making this happen. Basically how to find the leaks in code and fix it[image]

I tried profiler instruments in XCODE but it only shows the memory address of a leak but not referring me to the code where i could fix it